# Cannot access to the redux state from class component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have class component and I connect it with connect but when I want to access to state of redux it is `undefined`.

When I `console.log(this.props)` it shows the `props` and `mystate` but in the next line cannot access and it is `undefined`.

please help me.

---

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class myClass extends React.Component {

   render() {
       console.log(this.props);

           return this.props.mystate.map((person) => {
                return <h1>{person.name}</h1>
}
           )
       }
}




const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    mystate: state
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(myClass)
```

log result :

```
mystate: Array(2)
0: {id: "1000", name: "Bryan wong", status: "1"}
1: {id: "1001", name: "ng", status: "1"}
```

---

UPDATE
When I change class to functional component and `useState` it worked find means reducer is ok but I don't know why in class first is `undefined` and when I check with redux plugin in browser it shows it has data!

Comment: please post what `mystate` contains when you log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that **mystate** is just an **array** with Persons objects(with **name** property),you can try something like this.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'

    class myClass extends React.Component {

      Persons=()=>{
       if(this.props.mystate){
          return this.props.mystate.map((person) => {
             return <h1>{person.name}</h1>
           }    
         } 
       }

       render() {
           console.log(this.props);

           return(
           <div>{this.Persons()}</div>
           )
       }
    }




    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        mystate: state
    })


    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(myClass)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `myState` set to an empty array in your `initialState`.

Comment: i did it , in the log i can see and it is working fine

Comment: Can you add your reducer and initialState to the question?